# Make the prior record and current record in the same row

Tags: sql-server

I have this table that list action by user and by action date.

[image]

I need to pull the table and add the immediately last action to the table. Tried to join the table by itself on oldtable.id-1=newtable.id but the last row will be missing. Left Join is out of question because it's too slow. Any ideas to accomplish this? The output should look like below. Thank you for your help!!

[image]

Comment: When you say it is way too slow ... 1) does this table have a lot of rows (100k+ or 1M+)? 2) Are you allowed to add a new index to your table (I think it would solve your slowness)? 4) If there is a lot of data, do you need all of it, or just recent (week/month/year)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using SQL 2012 or later, you've got access to the LEAD and LAG window functions:

```
select [ID]
     , [User]
     , lag([Action]) over (partition by [user] order by [ActionDate]) as [OldAction]
     , [Action] as [NewAction]
     , lag([ActionDate]) over (partition by [user] order by [ActionDate]) as [OldActionDate]
     , [ActionDate] as [NewActionDate]
  from UserAction;
```